# Insert into table after pg dump

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures, psql, node-postgres

I used `pg_dump` to populate a table in new database. After that, I want to be able to insert rows into table using the `default autoincrementer` of the serial key. Here is what I have in table:

In this `table (smtable)`, `a` is the key (set as `serial`).

```
--data filled using pg dump
a  |  b
1     2
2     5
```

Now when I do the following statement:

```
INSERT INTO smtable VALUES(DEFAULT, 6)
        RETURNING a INTO id;
```

I get the following error:

```
[error: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "a_pkey"]
detail: 'Key (a)=(1) already exists.
```

How do I get this statement to insert `next_key` of the table..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might set the serial to the greatest number of your current id column to solve the issue. Since serial columns are associated with a sequence, just set it using this:

```
SELECT setval('smtable_a_seq', max(a)) FROM table;
```